# Как заставить код ждать завершения работы Timer ? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, таймер

Проблема в том, что после запуска функции  focusTime() следущая строчка кода работает паралельно с созданым таймером. В идеале нужно дождаться завершения работы таймера и потом уже продолжить.

```
...
    if sessions < 10 {
    focusTime()
    sessions += 1
    } else {
    print ("Good job!")
    }}

func focusTime () {
    createTimer()
    let focusCounter = 5
    timeLeft = focusCounter
    print("focus time started")
    runTimer()
}

func createTimer()  {
    if timer == nil {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(runTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }}

@objc func runTimer() {
    if timeLeft > 0 { timeLeft -= 1 }
    else {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы переписал ваш код следующим образом, чтобы второй раз таймер запускался изнутри `runTimer()`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var timer: Timer?
    var timeLeft = 3
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        startFocusTime1()
    }
    
    func startFocusTime1() {
        createTimer()
    }
    
    func startFocusTime2() {
        let focusCounter = 5
        timeLeft = focusCounter
        print("focus time started")
        runTimer() // возможно имеется в виду снова createTimer()?
    }
    
    func createTimer()  {
        if timer == nil {
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(runTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    }
    
    @objc func runTimer() {
        if timeLeft > 0 {
            timeLeft -= 1
            return
        }
        
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
        
        startFocusTime2()
    }
    
}
```